# Drools 6.0.1 - Rules not getting picked from JAR

Tags: java, drools, drools-guvnor

I am working on  DROOLS 6.0.1 application. I have my rule files (*.drl) packaged inside a separate project which is included as a jar file as a maven dependency. When I deploy my project, `KIEModule` is not able to find the rules files (which are packaged inside the jar above). I am not getting an error though but rules are not getting fired.

If I manually place the rules files under classpath say `WEB-INF/rules/*.drl` they are detected and rules are executed.

I was under impression that `KIEmodules` are auto discovered from anywhere in classpath.

Any pointers are appreciated. This is general question hence I have not included the comprehensive code files.
Everything start working once I place the `*.drl` files in the classpath (take them outside of jar).

Thanks

Comment: did you ever fix this problem?

Comment: Not really. We went live with reading rules from filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

Step 1 : Found the solution, the package with DLR must be declared inside your : "kmodule.xml"

Step2: you have to create [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fZMv.png)
Step3:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpaF5.png)